# Qt Toolbar button icons show in Windows after MinGW build, but disappear after being built with g++

Tags: windows, linux, qt, icons

I'm developing a PHP IDE similar to Eclipse, but much more light weight. For the interface I'm using Qt 4.4.3 which seems to be working great. I've primarily been using my Windows machine to do most of the coding in Eclipse CDT and using MinGW as the compiler.

A couple of days ago I took the code an put it on my Eee PC with Linux just to see if I could get it to build. Well, after getting build-essential, Qt, and Eclipse going, the program compiled just fine. However, when I start it up in Linux, all the icons on the toolbar of my program have disappeared. These are common icons like Cut, Copy, Paste, Open, New...  The build doesn't give me any warnings, and the toolbar acts like it has the icons (i.e. if the icons aren't available, there's a text label to show for the button. It doesn't show the text label so it thinks the images are there).

Any ideas on why the icons aren't showing up? The file structure is exactly the same, and the paths to the icons are correct. The resource file finds the images. I'm pretty new to Linux and developing on Linux, so I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How are you displaying the icons' images?

Comment: Did you keep in mind that in Linux, filenames are case-sensitive?

Comment: Could you add your .pro and your .qrc files?

Comment: If you are sure that those files are correct: did qmake run with no errors? And maybe you could post the code where you access those resources.

Answer (score 1):

Which image format, e.g. GIF, PNG, did you use for the icons? It might be that Qt on the target machine does not successfully load the [plugins](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qimageioplugin.html) for that format.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'strace -e file -o LOG ./YourBinary', and exit program immediately after startup.

Look through the LOG for 'file not found errors'. In mysterious cases like this it never hurts to double-check this way that paths are indeed correct